# I have a dataframe like this , How can i convert it into years and every column should come with mean value of all data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
             tavg   tmin    tmax    prcp
year                
1990-01-01  9.4     6.0     15.1    0.0
1990-01-02  17.9    7.3     24.3    0.0
1990-01-03  14.9    8.3     22.1    0.0
1990-01-04  20.9    14.6    28.2    0.0
1990-01-05  29.8    25.0    36.0    0.3
```

Expected output :

```
        tavg    tmin    tmax    prcp
year                
1990    9.2     5.0     15.1    0.0
1991    16.4    6.3     24.3    0.0
1992    12.3    8.3     22.1    0.0
1993    21.7    14.6    28.2    0.0
1994    28.6    25.0    36.0    0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract year from `year` column and aggregate `mean`:

```
print (df)
        year  tavg  tmin  tmax  prcp
0 1990-01-01   9.4   6.0  15.1   0.0
1 1990-01-02  17.9   7.3  24.3   0.0
2 1991-01-03  14.9   8.3  22.1   0.0
3 1991-01-04  20.9  14.6  28.2   0.0
4 1992-01-05  29.8  25.0  36.0   0.3


df = df.groupby(df['year'].dt.year).mean()
print (df)
       tavg   tmin   tmax  prcp
year                           
1990  13.65   6.65  19.70   0.0
1991  17.90  11.45  25.15   0.0
1992  29.80  25.00  36.00   0.3
```

Comment: @PREMKUMAR - What is `print (df.index[:3])` ?

Comment: Bro the output is coming for a mean value of all rows. I want the output for every year. plz see the expected outcome in the question. Kindly help me

Comment: @PREMKUMAR - There is some problem in data, what is `print (df.index[:3])` in original data?

Comment: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
this is output of df.index[:3]

Comment: @PREMKUMAR - and column `year` ? What is `print (df['year'].iloc[:3])` ?

Comment: bro see the output

Comment: 0   1990-01-01
1   1990-02-01
2   1990-03-01
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: @PREMKUMAR - answer was edited.

Comment: my dataset is the same as like in the question. your solution is working but i want it for every year separately.

Comment: i have dataset of everyday value for 15 years . i want to sum it for every years .  plz help me

Comment: @PREMKUMAR - `df = df.groupby(df['year'].dt.year).mean()` create each year separately. Unfortuantely not understand what is problem

Comment: tq so much bro. now working. great !!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to convert years column into datetime64[ns] type using the line, if df is your dataframe:

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["year"], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

and then, group by year as follow:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.year).mean()
```

Actually, you can't do operations on dates without converting it into datetime64[ns] type.
Good luck!

Comment: Bro the output is coming for a mean value of all rows. I want the output for every year. plz see the expected outcome in the question. Kindly help me